# Change text or background color of bootstraps date picker

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented the bootstrap date picker (see figure below). It's working as intended. The code look like this:

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <input name="departure" type="text" class="form-control" id="departure" required>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

The code for implementing the date picker:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
        startDate: "2014-12-01",
        endDate: "2016-01-01",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
});
```

Date picker:

[image: dtp]

When I change the background color of my HTML page like this:

```
body {
    background: #EDEDED !important; /* RGB Decimal :237, 237, 237 */
    color: #965B25 !important; /* RGB Decimal :150, 91, 37 */
}
```

The text in the date picker is also changed. The result of this is that you can not read any text inside the date picker box. **Is there a way to change the text color/background color of the date picker itself?**

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Marcus

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): why are you setting the `body`s background and color with `!important`?

Comment: Because bootstrap comes with an own CSS, and has already set those attributes. I'm overriding them like this

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't use `!important` in the `body` block. If you cascade these styles yours should be applied.

Comment: Wierd. I tried it before, and It didn't work then without !important, but I removed them and now, and it still works. It doesn't answer my question tho

Comment: Are you sure your CSS loads after the bootstrap? BTW: George's comment *does* answer your question.

Comment: it is trivlal to look at the rules that affect any element by simply using developer tools to inspect that element

Comment: Yes I'm sure. If it does answer my question, then please elaborate because I dont see how I can apply that answer to solve my problem. @abhitalks.

Comment: Makes no sense @charlietfl

Comment: the point is to inspect the elements and modify or add rules accordingly. Can even do live edits in dev tools

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do here. But I'm stuck. @charlietfl

Comment: provide a demo then, we can't write css based on an image or see what conflicts you have created

Comment: You could have created a fiddle demo and seen it yourself. Anyway, I have created a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/vk4bkgtz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
.datepicker {
background-color: #fff ;
color: #333 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue i faced for Bootstrap3 datetimepicker and i did the below change and it worked

```
  $('.datepicker').on(
        'dp.show',
        function(e) {
        $(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget").css(
        "background-color", "#3c3e43");
        });
```